# How to vary "private static final" parameter?

Tags: java, static, private, final

I am new to java and object oriented programming and I have a question. There is a huge java code which has multiple packages and scrapbooks (each has several classes). It has many "private static final" parameters with their values. Now, I need to make those values variable which means I need to change the value of those parameters and each time, run the code to get the result. It wont be easy if I change the code each time and run the code. I want to give the numbers one time to the code (like list of numbers) and run the code for that. Any idea how to do that with least changes to the current code? For example define new class and give all variables in that class as array and with a for loop like K_value=K(i) and change the code from e.g. "private static final int k = 10" to "private static final int k= K_value". 
To make it clear lets assume:

```
private static final K= 5
private static final Q= -5
private static final M= 1
```

and K can be:5, 10, 15
Q can be -5, -10, -15, -20
and M can be 1, 2
and I want to run the code with all/partial combinations of above values. e.g.: 1) K=5, Q=-5, M=1 and 2) K=5, Q=-5, M=2 3) K=5, Q=-10, M=1  and so on.

Comment: You can't. You simply have to define new variables (with different names, or in different classes) and refer to those instead.

Comment: Is this for a production environment or practice/tutorial? Different approaches should be considered in each scenario. By the way: what's with the downvotes? The question is clear and all constraints are given

Comment: You can initialize static fields using method calls.  A common way to do what you seem to be asking, is to initialize the field from a system property.  For example:   `private static final int MAX_THREADS = Integer.getInteger("com.example.myapp.maxThreads", 5);`  This allows you to override the default value on the command line with something like `-Dcom.example.myapp.maxThreads=10`.

Comment: *FYI:* There is no such thing as "`private static final` parameters", since a *parameter* cannot be `private` or `static`. Only *fields* (aka *instance variables*) can be `private` and/or `static`.

Comment: @Andreas there is "private static final" in the code and it is working properly.

Comment: @Zeynab `private static final int k = 10` declared a *field*, not a *parameter*. I'm commenting on your incorrect **terminology**.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your question in regards to the `least amount of changes` requirement. Any approach that is 'quick and dirty' will be marked with `@@@` and I would **urge** you to not use them in a production scenario (e.g. just use them for one-off testing purposes or some old inherited **non-critical** code). I will express some general thoughts about the outlined scenario afterwards.

1. Read an environment variable (or system property) into the static final variables and start the program multiple times with a different value for its environment variable / system property: `private static final int someConst = Integer.parseInt(System.getEnv("someConst"))` **@@@**
2. Make the variable non final and change the value after every run of your suggested for loop method. Please note that this is extremely fragile/dangerous/error-prone as the variables may only read once at e.g. the application startup **@@@**
3. Rewrite the components that use the given constants to require the value as a constructor or function parameter. Depending on the applications size or how confident you feel in refactoring an unknown code base this could prove to be difficult. Consider using this approach if you have a well tested application

When reading your question I noticed that the outlined scenario seems like an algorithm/logic which should operate on input values instead of constants (you described they are not constant anymore). If possible the code should be restructured to reflect these new circumstances: make it instantiatable (add a constructor parameter) for different values or add a parameter to the affected functions/classes. All of the suggested fixes are just workarounds to modify as little code as possible. My advice: rewrite this if the usage scenario is for a production environment and use one of the outlined hacky workarounds if this is a one-off tutorial/testing/exploration.

Comment: Thanks so much for helpful explanation. I will stick with the 3rd solution as you recommended and as I want to be organized logical approach for many time usage. Would you please explain a little more what you mean by "function parameter"? Do you mean I need to define new function that can set the values of those "private static final int" things. Is this all changes I should apply? I mean would that be fine if do not change "private static final int" parameters and just give them values (like give them "k" value which k is already defined in a function?)

Comment: and I am not sure how constructors would be applied here. Are they used to give value to the  "private static final int"? Sorry I am new to this field and my question might be too simple.

Comment: The third approach would remove the static final fields all together. You would make them non static by e.g. creating an object which holds the current value that should be used and passing it to all parts of the application that needs the value. You can store said object as a field or just pass it as a function parameter where it's needed. Using a custom object instead of just passing an int (or whatever data type you use) would also make it extendable if you need any more values or data in the future.

Don't worry about your questions, they are fine - everyone has to start somewhere :)

Comment: What you mean by "custom object"? So you mean I should remove all those "private static final" things and can not use them anymore? Why I can not substitute  "private static final int k = 10" with  "private static final int k = M" and then define M in somewhere else like in a method?

Comment: I edited the question and added K, Q and M as an example. So do you mean I should delete all those "private static final" things and redefine K, Q and M? Do you mean I should define K as an object and 5, 10, 15 as attributes of K? If yes, then I should define a class that K can be instantiated?

Comment: Yes delete / change K Q M into an object that holds these value (can be fields k, q, m). Give said object a speaking name, you know the context best :). Then use the new object as a parameter everywhere these values are needed (constructor or function parameter)

Comment: I will build a little code example for you later this day which should help you understand a little better

Comment: That would be great if you do so @roookeee

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/XMsXRyFX) is an example. I have wrapped the old way / classes in `OldCode` and the new approach in `NewCode`. You should use separate files for these classes :) This is a very reduced example as I don't know what kind of application you are building but it should suffice to understand what I am talking about. If you use the variant where the values are passed to the functions that need them you don't need the constructor in the example which could be quite beneficial

Comment: oh one more question. I do not want to change the values each time. For example one run should be with 1) K=5, Q=-5, M=1 and the next run should be 2) K=5, Q=-5, M=2 and the third run should be 3) K=5, Q=-10, M=1 and so on. How can I organize this? By for loop?

Comment: (note: this comment is in regard to the linked example classes) I would create a `List<AlgorithmParameters>` and add all variations to it and then do a for loop to process each element contained in the list and run your application / algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. What are those multiplications by 3 or 5?

Comment: and I have not seen "AlgorithmParameters parameters" structure before. Is this the whole name?

Comment: The multiplications were just some sample code to show that the values are used. The `AlgorithmParameters` class is just a wrapper class for your 3 variables as I explained earlier. It is a custom data class, it is nothing you should have seen before or a pattern - it's just a class to aggregate all your values

Comment: Thanks. I meant this expression: " private final AlgorithmParameters parameters;". Private final is clear but I do not understand "AlgorithmParameters parameters"

Comment: and where should I give values for each M, Q, K to be used later?

Comment: That is a field declaration of the class, I can't quite follow what you don't understand. See the example function (`exampleRun`) how to give M,Q,K values, it calls the constructor of `AlgorithmParameters` with the current value of `i` in the loop I gave as an example

Comment: I checked the code several times. Sorry I am asking obvious questions but it is unclear for me. I need to have something like double K[]={5, 10, 15} in the code. Where are the real values of K, Q and M defined?

Comment: As this discussion is becoming a bit lengthy and specific I will stop responding via comments and would like you to invite to a more personal discussion

Comment: I get error when press start chat because reputation is not enough to do so.